# Why does php strpos() sometimes does not work on Unicode character?

Tags: php, woocommerce, unicode, strpos

I'm building a system that categorizes woo-commerce products by their name, my product's name is in Hebrew.
I have to check in my code if a name of a product contains a Hebrew word.

if I write something like:

```
strpos(hebrev("סט של בגדים"),hebrev("סט"))
```

it will work properly but when I try to do it with a return from a function like here

```
strpos(hebrev($product->get_name()),hebrev("סט"))
```

it does not work it just returns null.
assigning the output of the function to a variable does not seem to work.

I tried it with and without hebrev() and it still does not work.

Am I doing anything wrong? is there any way to fix the problem?

Comment: Try to assign `$product->get_name()` to a variable, and then use it. Make sure that `$product->get_name()` is returning the required output.

Comment: yeah I tried it already doesn't seem to work

Comment: what does it return actually? Try using `echo $product->get_name()`

Comment: thats the weird part the output is correct its "סט בגדים"

Comment: doesn't work either and I checked with var_dump and it's already set to a string

Comment: That is so weird. Maybe a bug?

Comment: probably is, Have any idea how I can confirm if it really is?

Comment: Try using: `$foo = hebrev($product->get_name()); $bar = hebrev("סט"); strpos($foo,$bar)`

Comment: Accept my answer :)

Comment: You can upvote my answer too btw, was that you who upvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$foo = hebrev($product->get_name()); 
$bar = hebrev("סט"); 
strpos($foo,$bar);
```